# Xamarin c# xaml obfuscation data binding conflict

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, obfuscation, dotfuscator

I'm developing an xamarin application using xamarin forms.
I have a button in xaml file and onclick function in c#.

XAML

```
<Button Content="Button!" Click="OnButtonClick"  />
```

Code behind

```
void OnButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //some logic.
}
```

Before obfuscation, the application runs fine.
but after obfuscation,
In C#, the function name(OnButtonClick) is obfuscated
In xaml, the name (OnButtonClick) remains same.

because of this conflicts, application throws error.
Developing Tools 
Visual Studio 2015
Dotfuscator community edition
xamarin 4.0.4.4

Answer (score 3):

In most situations the XAML will be renamed correctly. We recently became aware of a bug, though, where Xamarin generates XAML/XML with an unusual version string, and Dotfuscator doesn't handle it. We're planning a fix but it won't be available until a new version of Visual Studio is released with the fix to Dotfuscator CE. (Our next Pro release will have the fix, if that is an option for you.) To work around the issue, you can [exclude the method from renaming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd551425.aspx).

Also it looks like you might have a mistake in your XAML syntax - I believe it should be `Clicked=`, not `Click=`.

Full disclosure: I work for PreEmptive Solutions.

Answer (score 1):

In the [MS Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.obfuscationattribute(v=vs.110).aspx), there's an `ObfuscationAttribute` that you can access

```
[ObfuscationAttribute(Exclude=true)]
void OnButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //some logic.
}
```

Comment: Thats a good option. ( ObfuscationAttribute). but, thats not available for PCL .  
I'm able to use it in Android Project but not for PCL.  
Thanks :smile: